# Why do some generated C# class properties not match the XSD attributes?

Tags: c#, xsd, xsd.exe

I'm generating C# classes from an OTA (Open Travel Alliance) XSD file. You can [download the XSD file from here](http://www.opentravel.org/2007B/FS_OTA_VehLocDetailsNotifRQ.xsd).

I create the C# class with the following command in a Visual Studio Command Prompt:

```
xsd FS_OTA_VehLocDetailsNotifRQ.xsd /classes /nologo
```

Within `OTA_VehLocDetailsNotifRQ.POS[0].RequestorID` I would expect to find an `ID` property. Yet the property generated by the XSD.exe tool is named `ID_Context`.

Can you explain why it does this, and whether I am able to force it to generate the correct (`ID`) property name?

Please don't suggest I edit the generated file as that is not a maintainable approach.

**Further edit after accepting the answer:**

Looking at the XSD more closely and replacing the references with their attribute group definitions, the ID attribute can be seen in its attribute group:

```
<xs:attributeGroup name="UniqueID_Group">
  <xs:attribute name="URL" type="xs:anyURI" />
  <xs:attribute name="Type" type="OTA_CodeType" use="required" />
  <xs:attribute name="Instance" type="StringLength1to32" />
  <xs:attributeGroup name="ID_Group">
    <xs:attribute name="ID" type="StringLength1to32" use="required" />
  </xs:attributeGroup>
  <xs:attribute name="ID_Context" type="StringLength1to32" use="optional" />
</xs:attributeGroup>
```

I believe this to be a bug in the XSD tool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's see....

- the `RequestorID` contains complex content of type `UniqueID_Type`
- `UniqueID_Type` contains a reference to a group of attributes called `UniqueID_Group`
- `UniqueID_Group` is an attribute group and contains the following attributes:

  - `URL`
  - `Type`
  - `Instance`
  - a reference to an `ID_Group`
  - `ID_Context`

I guess the C# code "ID_Context" is generated because of the "ID_COntext" attribute in that attribute group... I don't see anything wrong with that.

But I do agree - that `ID_Group` should include an "ID" property, but it seems xsd.exe has dropped that nested reference to the `ID_Group` - for whatever reason... it does appear to be a problem others have stumbled across in other scenarios, as well. Looks like xsd.exe cannot handle this task :-(

Maybe also check out this discussion:

http://groups.google.com/group/OTA-Impl-Forum/browse_thread/thread/fa476cfb6e1fa7f7

Update: I also tried the `svcutil.exe` from WCF (.NET 3.0 and up) - no luck either :-(

> Error: Type 'DateOrTimeOrDateTimeType'
>   in namespace
>   'http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05'
>   cannot be imported. **Simple types with **
>   `<union>` content are not supported.**
>   Either change the schema so that the
>   types can map to data contract types
>   or use ImportXmlTyp e or use a
>   different serializer.

Comment: Wow, I missed that step; well done. As you say, the skipping of the `ID_Group` is the problem. What a pity it's attribute.

Answer (score 2):

A bit late, but I think I maybe found the solution to your problem (and right now my problem too):

http://www.opentravelcommunityforum.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=19

I didn't tried yet, but I'm about to.

Comment: I don't think that solves this particular issue, but if it does please share the fix here. THANKS!

Comment: Yes, it worked for me. I had the same issue and by nesting I could fix it!